# IaaS Azure Diagnostics won't start. Missing assemblies

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, iaas

When I try to enable Iaas Azure Diagnostics on my VM, I encounter the following errors. I was able to track down the local log files and found these entries.

How do you repair the Azure Diagnostics extension, without recycling the VM?

**"C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.3.1.6\Logs\DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.log"**

```
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:43 AM] No DiagnosticsPlugin is running.
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:43 AM] Killing any DiagnosticsPlugin that might remain.
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:43 AM] Killing any MonAgentHost that might remain.
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Diagnostics plugin stopped successfully
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Resetting DiagnosticPlugin
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Error: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:53 AM] DiagnosticsPlugin launch failed with exit code -108
DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:06:01 AM] DiagnosticPlugin exited with code -108
```

**"C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.3.1.6\Logs\DiagnosticsPlugin.log"**

```
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Found namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration in schema schema\WADPrivateConfigSchema.xsd
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] WadCfg is provided in initial configuration. Using that to initialize Diagnostics.
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration"><WadCfg><DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration"><DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" /><Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M"><IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" /><FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" /></Directories><WindowsEventLog><DataSource name="Application!*" /><DataSource name="System!*" /><DataSource name="Security!*" /></WindowsEventLog><Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" /></DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration></WadCfg></PublicConfig>
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Private setting is loaded
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Checkpoint file is presentC:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.3.1.6\WAD0103\Configuration\Checkpoint.txt
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] Will use local resource directory C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.3.1.6\WAD0103
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:44 AM] System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.SecUtil.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.SecUtil.dll'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.StandardConfig.EncryptKey(String key, String thumbprint)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.StandardConfig..ctor(String nameSpace, Int32 eventVersion, Int64 overallQuota, String accountName, String accountKey, String accountUri, String accountCertStore, Int32 retention, String thumbprint)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadParser.Translate(String baseMaResourcePath, Int32 actualDiskQuota, String& fullConfigFilePath)

DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:48 AM] Failed to convert WAD1.1 config to Monagent config format
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [1/10/2015 1:05:52 AM] DiagnosticPlugin.exe exit with code -108
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to rebuild is to uninstall then reinstall the VM Extension.